# How to get an uncle number using uncle hash?

Tags: uncle-blocks

Let's say, we have following block: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/7375
It has two uncles:

```
0xa9e3fe7090c12fd6db3cec305d21437b0c968188becafc099f4324964015d27a      
0x33eace2f6ffee2a214053c538f1fe2998a53a4bfc0a02000bc5280af7f166396
```

The following link shows detailed information about first uncle:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/uncle/0xa9e3fe7090c12fd6db3cec305d21437b0c968188becafc099f4324964015d27a

I am interested how I can get a detailed information about each uncle, like in the link above. Is there some API for uncle data?

I need this in order to calculate uncle reward.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why isn't it just the same URL but using the second hash instead of the first?

Comment: Here is my issue: I'd like to calculate uncle reward, the formula is (U_n + 8 - B_n) * R / 8, where U_n = uncle number. When a new block occurs, it shows only uncle hashes. So I need to understand how I can get uncle numbers. Most probably there's something which I don't understand

Comment: The link you provide links to the first uncle with the first hash. If you change the hash to use the second hash instead, you see the block number for the second uncle which happens to be the same as the first one--but that makes sense. They are brothers, and they are brothers of this block's parent, so they would have the same height as the parent--one less than the block. (I'm not sure if this happens every time [that uncle is one less than current block], but it makes sense here.)

Comment: You are not right, see this block: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/4447

Comment: Oh. I get it now. Maybe your asking "is there an API" as opposed to "where is the link"? Sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66243/discussion-between-ivan-ursul-and-thomas-jay-rush).

Comment: So in this case, one of the uncles was a brother of the parent, and the other a brother of the grandparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [eth_getUncleByHashAndIndex](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_getunclebyblockhashandindex) RPC function to retrieve the block that holds the block number of that uncle. First retrieve the block in question. It will contain a list of uncle hashes. Then use eth_getUncleByHash to get the block that is represented by that hash.